# Why Emmet and brackets autoexpand php tag wrong and how to fix it?

Tags: php, autocomplete, emmet, adobe-brackets

I've installed Brackets - and added Emmet to it. Both of them are great, and works like a charm, except for one small detail. 
When I try to expand php, it expands to `<php>` instead of `<?php ?>`
which is very annoying, since I'm inserting decent amount of php code into html. 
Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "php" expansion to `<php></php>` is preset in `snippets.json` file. According to [Emmet documentation](http://docs.emmet.io/customization/snippets/) you should add your custom file `snippets*.json` and define the abbreviation there. I tried to change abbreviation for "php" using custom `snippets-php.json` file and it did not work. I also tried to change it in original `snippets.json` file and it did not work either.
There is a [thread](https://github.com/emmetio/brackets-emmet/issues/55) here with somewhat workaround to try to make php snippet as a `cLike` instead of `php`. Try and see if it works for you.